# Dockerfile Build Error

Tags: linux, docker, dockerfile, shinyproxy

I am trying to build a dockerfile for a Euler App to test ShinyProxy via "http://www.shinyproxy.io/deploying-apps/"

I am using the dockerfile from that link.

Upon using the command `sudo docker build -t openanalytics/shinyproxy-template .`

I get an error while the build is processing that:

```
Error: unexpected end of input
Execution halted
The command '/bin/sh -c R -e "install.packages(c('shiny', 'rmarkdown', repos='https://cloud.r-project.org/')" ' returned a non-zero code: 1.
```

I am curious why I am getting this error as this is the same exact command from the dockerfile.

What can I do to resolve this.

-Thanks

Comment: Are you using the Dockerfile from that link or your own?

Comment: I am using the dockerfile from that link.

Comment: Docker tells you what went wrong. When it tried to execute the install command, it got a non 0 return code, so the install failed. That's why the rest of the build process didn't finish. You'd have to do a little experimenting to see what caused the install to fail

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Look closely at the syntax of the R install library line and you will see its missing a closing parenthesis

I just manually fixed that syntax and it correctly builds that step

***correct syntax***

```
RUN R -e "install.packages(c('shiny', 'rmarkdown'), repos='https://cloud.r-project.org/')"
```

build it as

```
docker build --tag r_base .
```

NOTE - as docker build progresses it then fails later attempting to

```
COPY euler /root/euler

lstat euler: no such file or directory
```

To troubleshot this just comment out all Dockefile lines from offending onward and replace bottom line with

```
CMD ["/bin/bash"]
```

then it will build correctly and allow you to login to running container to further troubleshoot

```
docker run -ti r_base bash
```

I know nothing of R so will leave it to the reader to fix euler COPY ... evidently you must have euler sitting in your local directory prior to issuing the docker build command

...now after you issue above docker run command then from its internal to container prompt issue

```
cd /
find . | grep  Rprofile.site

./usr/lib/R/etc/Rprofile.site
```

That looks good so leave commented out its COPY in Dockerfile

Comment: Thanks for the helpful answer!